# ESLint: Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'getTimeParts'.(class-methods-use-this)

Tags: javascript

ESLint ругается на отсутствие 'this' в методе 'getTimeParts'. Как можно исправить код в нужный формат?

```js
    class DigitalClock {
          constructor(element) {
            this.element = element;
          }
        
          start() {
            this.update();
        
            setInterval(() => {
              this.update();
            }, 500);
          }
        
          update() {
            const parts = this.getTimeParts();
            const minuteFormatted = parts.minute.toString().padStart(2, '0');
            const timeFormatted = `${parts.hour}:${minuteFormatted}`;
            const amPm = parts.isAm ? 'AM' : 'PM';
        
            this.element.querySelector('.clock-time').textContent = timeFormatted;
            this.element.querySelector('.clock-ampm').textContent = amPm;
          }
        
          getTimeParts() {
            const now = new Date();
        
            return {
              hour: now.getHours() % 12 || 12,
              minute: now.getMinutes(),
              isAm: now.getHours() < 12,
            };
          }
        }
        
        const clockElement = document.querySelector('.clock');
        const clockObject = new DigitalClock(clockElement);
        
        clockObject.start();
```

Comment: Я не знаю ответа на данный вопрос, но чисто подумать. Попробуйте метод объявить статичным.

Comment: Скорее всего ESLint недоумевает по поводу того, зачем функции быть методом если внутри нее нет обращения к объекту. Это ошибка смысловая. Если добавить `static` то может перестанет ругаться...

Comment: Да, если добавить static, то частично проблема решается, однако далее строка с const parts = this.getTimeParts(); становится недоступной - static member is not accesible.

Comment: Статический метод - метод КЛАССА, а не экземпляра класса - объекта. То есть, обращаться к нему можно только `DigitalClock.getTimeParts()`. Это разные стихии))) Одним словом, если вам нужен доступ к этому методу как методу экземпляра, то забейте на Lint) В конце концов, вы решаете вопрос инкапсуляции кода, возможно. Ничего криминального нет.

Comment: Короче, как я понял, это нюансы линта, т.к. в данном случае это не несет какой либо ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявленый метод `getTimeParts()` не обращается к экземпляру класса с использованием ключевого слова `this`, поэтому `ESLint` считает (достаточно логично), что эта функция могла бы быть размещена и вне объявления класса. Ведь она не потребляет и не преобразовывает какие-либо свойcтва объекта, методом которого она должна являться.

Казалось бы объявление метода с ключевым словом `static` решает проблему, но теперь из самого экземпляра класса - объекта - доступа к этому методу не будет. Обращаться к нему можно только `DigitalClock.getTimeParts()` - как к методу самого класса как функции.

Если убрать синтаксис `class`, то ваш код можно переделать следующим образом. И здесь хорошо видно, что статический метод - это просто свойство функции-конструктора (функция является объектом, а объекту можно добавлять свойства). Поэтому и в `DigitalClock.prototype.update()` идет обращение к `DigitalClock.getTimeParts()` , а не к `this.getTimeParts()`.

```js
function DigitalClock(element) {
    this.element = element;
}

DigitalClock.prototype.start = function(){
    this.update();

    setInterval(() => {
    this.update();
    }, 500);
};

DigitalClock.prototype.update = function(){
    const parts = DigitalClock.getTimeParts();
    const minuteFormatted = parts.minute.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const timeFormatted = `${parts.hour}:${minuteFormatted}`;
    const amPm = parts.isAm ? 'AM' : 'PM';

    this.element.querySelector('.clock-time').textContent = timeFormatted;
    this.element.querySelector('.clock-ampm').textContent = amPm;
}

DigitalClock.getTimeParts = function(){
    const now = new Date();

    return {
    hour: now.getHours() % 12 || 12,
    minute: now.getMinutes(),
    isAm: now.getHours() < 12,
    };
}

const clockElement = document.querySelector('.clock');
const clockObject = new DigitalClock(clockElement);

clockObject.start();
```

```html
<div class="clock">
    <div class="clock-time"></div>
    <div class="clock-ampm"></div>
  
</div>
```

В целом, необращение к `this` внутри метода класса не является ошибкой. Отчасти, это можно считать логическим недоразумением - не больше. Код будет работать.

Comment: _«... задачу инкапсуляции, то есть заключения всего кода в объявленый класс без функций в глобальной области видимости»_ - инкапсуляция это другое, она решает совсем иную задачу. Вот логическом недоразумении, написано верно (излишне напихивать общие утилити-функции в объект).

Comment: @yar85 истинная инскапсуляция в JS, может, не существует или достигается путем корявых замыканий. Но в целом, инкапсуляция - объединение всех данных и функций в одну сущность, здесь - в класс. Доступ к этой функции возможен через экземпляр класса, а не из глобальной области. В целом, для JS это и есть инкапсуляция. Свое понимание этого вопроса уберу)))

Comment: Почему то все пытаются притянуть JS к стандартам ООП языков и ну никак это не получается, только отчасти и через очень обходные пути. Так для меня инкапсуляция - не вопрос безопасности или незменяемости или непереписываемости переменных и методов, а логически очерченная область данных и методов, содержащих все сама в себе.

Comment: _«в целом, инкапсуляция - объединение всех данных и функций в одну сущность»_ - в этом определении та же ошибка, что и в первом: не учитывается "родной" смысловой контекст термина. Инкапсуляция призвана не только включать _относящуюся к объекту_ реализацию в объект, но и _ограничивать доступ_ к этой реализации. Вот в этой части, у вас с автором вопроса и кроется непонимание, хоть и по-разному. Конечно, я не против индивидуальных толкований (в своей голове каждый сам хозяин) - всего лишь обратил внимание на то что индивидуальное распространилось дальше мыслей, т.к. оно несет потенциальный вред.

Comment: И с ООП, у JS по-моему все в порядке - оно присутствует в той мере, и в той форме, которые возможны с учетом особенностей языка. Да и никто тут пока не утверждал, что модификаторы доступа в определении объектных свойств являются единственным способом управления доступом. Если же есть предубеждения/"фу" насчет замыканий, то рекомендую обратить внимание например на Lua, где большинство задач ООП решается довольно инфернальным метапрограммированием)) Стоит ли пытаться сравнивать заведомо несравнимое (такое, как особенности языков)?

Comment: Ответ - всегда индивидуальное мнение, а однозначные ответы - "ДА" и "НЕТ" - не более того.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127017/discussion-between-yar85-and-leonid).